# ckan datastore_search API with multiple filters

Tags: ajax, api, ckan

I'm calling this dataset:

http://data.edinburghopendata.info/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=4cfb5177-d3db-4efc-ac6f-351af75f9f92

with an AJAX call :

```
    var data = {
      resource_id: '4cfb5177-d3db-4efc-ac6f-351af75f9f92',
      filters: '{"BankTypeNa": "Packaging", "BankTypeNa": "Compost Bins"}',
      limit : 4757
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://data.edinburghopendata.info/api/action/datastore_search',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        markers = data.result.records;        
        showMarkers();
      }
    });
```

which is giving results only for the second filter.

[http://data.edinburghopendata.info/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=4cfb5177-d3db-4efc-ac6f-351af75f9f92&filters={%22BankTypeNa%22:%20%22Packaging%22,%20%22BankTypeNa%22:%20%22Compost%20Bins%22}](http://data.edinburghopendata.info/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=4cfb5177-d3db-4efc-ac6f-351af75f9f92&filters=%7B%22BankTypeNa%22:%20%22Packaging%22,%20%22BankTypeNa%22:%20%22Compost%20Bins%22%7D)

Is there a way, or another parameter I could use to get both "Packaging" and "Compost Bins" in my search results?

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if somebody can prove me wrong, but its not possible. In theory you would just put the two values in an array as the value for the BankTypeNa key, e.g.

```
filters: '{"BankTypeNa": ["Packaging", "Compost Bins"]}'
```

But this doesn't work for text columns (an SQL error results). It does work for numeric ones [1]. It would be good to submit an issue on that at [github.com/ckan/ckan](https://github.com/ckan/ckan).

I would use the datastore_search_sql endpoint instead, i.e.

```
var data = {
  "resource_id": "4cfb5177-d3db-4efc-ac6f-351af75f9f92",
  "sql": "SELECT * FROM \"4cfb5177-d3db-4efc-ac6f-351af75f9f92\" WHERE \"BankTypeNa\" LIKE 'Packaging' OR \"BankTypeNa\" LIKE 'Compost Bins'",
  "limit": 4757
};
```

[1] [CKAN: delete a list of records within the DataStore in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227226/ckan-delete-a-list-of-records-within-the-datastore-in-a-single-query#41264919)