# CKAN: delete a list of records within the DataStore in a single query

Tags: ckan

**NOTE**: My original problem is to delete all the records except for the last `N` ones, but guessing such a thing is impossible with CKAN API, I've come up with the following solution:

1. To get the `total` ammount of records using `datastore_search`.
2. To get the ID of the `first` record in the previous search.
3. To obtain the IDs of all the records from the `first` record ID to `total-N`.

So, my question is: how to delete all the identified IDs in a single query? I've tried the following:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_delete" -d '{"filters":{"_id":1,"_id":2,"_id":3},"force":"true","resource_id":"a43bfb04-7a8b-4624-a06a-25f4165e5b2a"}' -H "Authorization: xxx"
{"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_delete", "success": true, "result": {"filters": {"_id": 3}, "resource_id": "a43bfb04-7a8b-4624-a06a-25f4165e5b2a"}}
```

But only the record regarding the last ID (`3`) was removed.

Of course, an array did not work as well:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_delete" -d '{"filters":[{"_id":1},{"_id":2},{"_id":3}],"force":"true","resource_id":"a43bfb04-7a8b-4624-a06a-25f4165e5b2a"}' -H "Authorization: xxx"
{"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_delete", "success": false, "error": {"__type": "Validation Error", "filters": ["filters must be either a dict or null."]}}
```

Any idea? Or should I perform a query for each record aimed to be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-answering. After trying several combinations, I've found this works:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_delete" -d '{"filters":{"_id":[1,2]},"force":"true","resource_id":"a43bfb04-7a8b-4624-a06a-25f4165e5b2a"}' -H "Authorization: xxx"
```

I.e. a dictionary has to be sent with a single (key,value) pair, the `_id` and an **array** of values for the `_id`, respectively.